# F# is it possible to exclude one member of an record from structural equality?

Tags: f#

Example, nevermind the utility of it:

```
type Rec = ( int * obj )  
let r1 = (1, o1)
let r2 = (1, o2)
r1=r2   // i would like it to be true. I mean the second member to be excluded from structural equality
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you want this?

Comment: Yes, it seems it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this isn't a record, but a type alias.

I think the best approach would be to define a new operator.

```
let inline (====) a b = (fst a ) = (fst b)
```

Comment: I need to add this objects to a Set, or as keys to a Map...

Comment: In that case, the duplicate linked by mark is the correct answer